# UIImage imageNamed - I want to get the iPhone version on iPad

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have a set of icons that on one of my views differs on iPhone and iPad (iPad Icons are much bigger) but on an other view I need the same small icons on iPhone and iPad.

So I went to the asset catalog and for the same image made iPhone and iPad versions by drag and dropping.

Can I now somehow when i ask for an `[UIImage imageNamed:]` tell it to give me the iPhone version regardless if the app is running on an iPhone or iPad?

Or will I have to create a separate asset for those images?

Comment: Simple. Just remove ipad image.

Comment: Why don't you put two set of icons one for ipad and iphone and 1 for common ?

Comment: Sure I could do that... i was just wondering if there is a better solution...
Like using device specific images but then also being able to get the one specific image i really want now...

Answer (score 0):

just make your image set "Universal"

Answer (score 0):

```
#define IS_IPAD_DEVICE      [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad

[UIImage imageNamed:(IS_IPAD_DEVICE)?@"IpadImageName.png":@"iPhoneImageName.png"]
```